# forwarding to action of a controller with no area from view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, view, logout

In my **_BootstrapLayout.basic.cshtml**
I currently am using following code to forward the user's click event to controller

```
@Html.ActionLink("Log Out", "LogOff", "Account")
```

The account controller lies in folder controllers which is there by default ( not inside an area). However, whenever user clicks logout button he/she is forwarded to following link

```
http://localhost:38195/Hardware/Account/LogOff
```

I have a area called hardware, but i don't know why it is forwarding me to to that area. What can I do so that I get forwarded to account controller that has no area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What can I do so that I get forwarded to account controller that has no area?

You can explicitly tell it to:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Log Out", "LogOff", "Account", new { area = "" }, null)
```

Comment: Thank you. I had tried to explicitly mention the area but i wasn't working the proper way, as I didn't have null after the `new {area=""}`. What is that `null` part for? I'll accept the answer once I'm allowed to (after 9 mins)

Comment: `null` is to invoke the proper overload taking `htmlAttributes`.